# Not able to set label text in asp.net master page controls from content page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, popup, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to change the text of label in master page which is inside modal and from content page i am trying to set the text.
This is my master page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 maximum-
    scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../Style/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?
    family=Lato:300,400,700,300italic,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" 
    type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-footable/0.1.0/css/footable.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
    <body>
    <div id="header">
        <form id="Form1" runat="server">
            <header>
            </header>
            <div class="container-fluid" id="body">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content" style="width: 400px;margin: 0 auto;">
                            <div class="modal-header" runat="server">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title"><asp:Label ID="lblMasterMessage" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label> </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblMasterbodyMessage" runat="server" Text="gh" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <footer class="panel-footer white">
                <div class="row">
                </div>
            </footer>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

script in child page which opens modal:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function openModal(message) {
          $('#myModal').modal('show');
      }
 </script>
```

code behind child page calling the script and changing text of label in modalpopup

```
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "LaunchServerSide", "$(function() { openModal(); });", true);
    Label lblMaster = (Label)Master.FindControl("lblMasterbodyMessage");
    string message = "something";
    lblMaster.Text = message;
```

i also tried the second approach by setting properties in master page but text in the popup is not getting updated. any help will be appreciated

Comment: at first i'm not able to find any label with id `lblMasterbodyMessage` in your master page second `$(function() { openModal(); });` this closure is not needed simply you can  pass a simple function name `openModal();`

Comment: changes done...

Answer (score 1):

Best approach will be to provide a get/set property in your master page that will accept value and assign it to the label value property.

> Master Page

```
public partial class MasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public string MasterBodyMessage // you can use some meaningfull name over here.
    {
        get { return this.lblMasterbodyMessage.Text; }
        set { this.lblMasterbodyMessage.Text = value; }
    }  
}
```

> Child Page

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "LaunchServerSide", "$(function() { openModal(); });", true);
var master = this.Master as MasterPage;
if (master != null)
{
    master.MasterBodyMessage = "Some Meaningful Message!!!";
}
```

Else you can do some work around using javascript/jQuery to add message into label in master page. For this you will need to amend following changes.

> HTML Aspx Page

```
<div class="modal-content" style="width: 400px;margin: 0 auto;">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button aria-label="Close" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"><label id="lblMasterMessage"></label></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <label id="lblMasterbodyMessage"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

> Code Behind Page

```
string message = "Some Meaningful Message!!!";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "LaunchServerSide", "openModal('"+ message +"');", true);
```

> jQuery Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function openModal(message) {
          $('#myModal').modal('show');
         $('#lblMasterbodyMessage').html(message);
      }
 </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, second approch is working but first approch is still facing same issue of pastback

Comment: Pleasure helping you out.

Answer (score 0):

**Specify your master page class name in TypeName attribute of MasterType directive.**

```
<%@ MasterType TypeName="MasterPageClassName" %>
```

Now you can access your public properties as this.Master.propertyname

Also try by moving your code from page load event to PreRenderComplete event of page.

That'll solve you're problem

Comment: Check this link it'll help https://forums.asp.net/t/1367012.aspx?updating+master+page+based+on+content+page+condition